# Добавление файла в <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fileupload

Предположим, что существует форма, содержащая поле для загрузки файлов: `<input type='file'>`. Есть ли возможность написать такой скрипт, чтобы при его выполнении в данное поле грузился файл, например, из папки на ПК?

Либо чтобы в форму грузился файл как-то иначе. Конечный смысл скрипта в том, чтобы загрузить в форму файл и отправить его при помощи скрипта. С отправкой всё понятно: через `.submit()` делается, а вот как загрузить файл в поле `type="file"`?

Способ загрузки (передачи) файла в форму не важен. Можно из папки на ПК, можно еще как-нибудь.

Answer (score 5):

Невозможно. Из браузера нет доступа к файловой системе компьютера. И это сделано с целью защиты.